# Rubocop using wrong version of Ruby - Fails

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I've re-installed RVM, Ruby and all gems using rvm implode. When I run rubocop, I receive an error that it is using 2.5 (which I did not explicitly install but seems to come with RVM's Ruby 2.5.1)

Note the line I have highlighted with * * - this may be the issue?

```
$ which ruby
/Users/Will/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby
$ rvm use 2.5.1
Using /Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1
$ rubocop
Inspecting 604 files


0 files inspected, no offenses detected
Unknown Ruby version: 2.5
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rubocop-0.49.1/lib/rubocop/processed_source.rb:131:in `parser_class’
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rubocop-0.49.1/lib/rubocop/processed_source.rb:138:in `create_parser’
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rubocop-0.49.1/lib/rubocop/processed_source.rb:94:in `parse’
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rubocop-0.49.1/lib/rubocop/processed_source.rb:36:in `initialize’
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rubocop-0.49.1/lib/rubocop/processed_source.rb:17:in `new’
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rubocop-0.49.1/lib/rubocop/processed_source.rb:17:in `from_file’
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rubocop-0.49.1/lib/rubocop/runner.rb:334:in `get_processed_source’
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rubocop-0.49.1/lib/rubocop/runner.rb:110:in `block in file_offenses’
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rubocop-0.49.1/lib/rubocop/runner.rb:121:in `file_offense_cache’
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rubocop-0.49.1/lib/rubocop/runner.rb:109:in `file_offenses’
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rubocop-0.49.1/lib/rubocop/runner.rb:100:in `process_file’
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rubocop-0.49.1/lib/rubocop/runner.rb:78:in `block in each_inspected_file’
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rubocop-0.49.1/lib/rubocop/runner.rb:75:in `each’
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rubocop-0.49.1/lib/rubocop/runner.rb:75:in `reduce’
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rubocop-0.49.1/lib/rubocop/runner.rb:75:in `each_inspected_file’
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rubocop-0.49.1/lib/rubocop/runner.rb:67:in `inspect_files’
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rubocop-0.49.1/lib/rubocop/runner.rb:39:in `run’
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rubocop-0.49.1/lib/rubocop/cli.rb:82:in `execute_runner’
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rubocop-0.49.1/lib/rubocop/cli.rb:28:in `run’
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rubocop-0.49.1/bin/rubocop:13:in `block in <top (required)>'
*/Users/Will/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime’*
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rubocop-0.49.1/bin/rubocop:12:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/rubocop:23:in `load’
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/rubocop:23:in `<main>'
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval’
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3):

Support for Ruby 2.5 was added to Rubocop in [version `0.52.0`](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#new-features-14). But you are using `0.49.1`.

You need to update Rubocop to at least version `0.52.0` or even better update to the latest version (which is `0.63.1` as of today).

Depending on your setup you simply need to run `bundle update rubocop` or you might need to specify the desired version in your `Gemfile` first.

Answer (score 0):

Found this thread when my VScode was looking for rubo cop gem installed within ruby 2.6 when it should have been looking within 2.7.

Not sure if this was the fix or if it was a number of other things but last thing I tried that work was setting the ruby version globally to `2.7`

I use rbenv so was able to do `rbenv global 2.7.4` and quit/restart vscode and the errors went away.